# Python - List Index Out Of Range

Tags: python, download, http-headers

Odd issue. I found a script download files, and have been using it for quite some time on my local machine without issues. However, after uploading it to HostGator's server, I've been getting this error whenever executing it, except this has never happened on my local machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SocialMonitor.py", line 39, in <module>
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**This is the terminal command I'm running (after CD to the python script directory):**

```
/opt/python27/bin/python2.7 ./SocialMonitor.py
```

**And last, the download script up until the error:**

```
url = "http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=21&feed=rss2"

file_name = 'dustinstatus.xml'
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(rootDir + "/feeds/" + file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
```

I've tried googling around for this error except I never got any results that would help fix something like this. As I said before, this never happens on my local machine, only on the HostGator server. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested, I added these two lines of code just before my script goes to get the headers.

```
print "Printing for Meta: " + str(meta)
print "Printg for Meta.GetHeaders: " + str(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
```

For the first command, it returns this:

```
Printing for Meta: Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 04:03:26 GMT
```

For the second however, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SocialMonitor.py", line 40, in <module>
    print "Printg for Meta.GetHeaders: " + str(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
IndexError: list index out of rang
```

Now, the list being empty makes sense, but the big question is why is it returning empty? Is it because I'm running the Python script on the same server box as the website itself?

Comment: first thing to do would be to ensure the python versions are the same on the local and remote boxes

Comment: `print` is your friend.  Just before the error insert print statements to print `meta`. And print `meta.getheaders("Content-Length")`  This should give you a hint as to what you are getting and why it's a zero-length list.

Comment: `meta.getheaders("Content-Length")` is returning an empty list.

Comment: Updated my first post with print results, and an extra comment!

Comment: Reading the answers and the comments, you seem to be under the impression that the server will always send you a `Content-Length` header. In reality, HTTP servers might not send that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you run it from hostgator you are not getting any content with the "Content-Length" http header - which means that most likely you are not being able to read the URL at all from there.

The easiest way to confirm that is trying to retrieve the page contents using the Python console from within hostgator itself (I don't knpw if you have shell access, it would be required) 
If you have, just run Python in interactive mode, and try something like:

```
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen("http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=21&feed=rss2").read()

print len(html)
```

If it is zero, that is it - the outgoing request is being blocked from within their service.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a clue from inspecting all the headers:

```
>>> import urllib2 as urlmodule
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> url = "http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=21&feed=rss2"
>>> u = urlmodule.urlopen(url)
>>> meta = u.info()
>>> pp(meta.headers)
['Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 04:36:53 GMT\r\n',
 'Server: Apache mod_qos/9.69 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlim
ited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635\r\n',
 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT\r\n',
 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0\
r\n',
 'Pragma: no-cache\r\n',
 'X-Pingback: http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/xmlrpc.php\r\n',
 'ETag: "ecae4ff5933219080eefaf5d7ef071ac"\r\n',
 'X-Mobilized-By: WordPress Mobile Pack 1.2.4\r\n',
 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=19aa94f1362e971400ed688ada0bd8cd; path=/\r\n',
 'Set-Cookie: wpmp_switcher=desktop; expires=Sun, 20-Jan-2013 04:36:53 GMT; path
=/\r\n',
 'Set-Cookie: _percent_mobile_c=531880547167941_1327124213_1138162253296621; exp
ires=Sun, 20-Jan-2013 04:36:53 GMT; path=/\r\n',
 'Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 02:48:46 GMT\r\n',
 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n',
 'X-Cache: MISS from proxy5.mel.dft.com.au\r\n',
 'X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy5.mel.dft.com.au:80\r\n',
 'Via: 1.1 proxy5.mel.dft.com.au:80 (Lusca/LUSCA_HEAD-r14809)\r\n',
 'Connection: close\r\n']
>>> print meta.getheaders("Content-Length")
[]
>>>
```

or you could just ignore all that and try the read anyway:

```
>>> guff = u.read()
>>> len(guff)
6179
>>> guff[:100]
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<rss version="2.0"\n\txmlns:content="ht
tp://purl.org/rss/1.0/mo'
>>> guff[-100:]
's-update-2/feed/</wfw:commentRss>\n\t\t<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>\n\t\t
</item>\n\t</channel>\n</rss>\n'
>>>
```